# Cannot Select .Net Core Version for New Projects

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

Until recently, when creating a .Net Core project, I've been able to select what version of Core to use for it.  Since a recent update of Visual Studio 2019, any library project I've created for .Net Core has defaulted to version 3.0.  There do not appear to be any options during project creation to select a different version.

For the time being, I need to create projects using .Net Core 2.2, so I'm wondering if anyone knows how to get that option back.  For now, I've just been manually changing the target version after creation, but that seems hacky, and I suppose it may be leaving me with bundled references I don't need, or omitting ones that I do.

**Update**

After installing tons of SDKs, I still do not see the option to choose a framework upon project creation.  The [documentation for Visual Studio 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-new-project?view=vs-2019) shows the option as it appears for .NET Framework projects:

[image]

... but when creating .NET Core or Standard projects, I am not presented with the option to choose the version:
[image]

Is the policy, now, that all projects default to the latest, and if you want something else, you have to change it in the project properties?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have some version of the 2.2.x SDK installed?

Comment: @ESG - Yes, it appears I have 2.2.203 (x64) installed.

Comment: Just to make sure, what's the output of `dotnet --list-sdks`?

Comment: .NET Core SDK versions must match their Visual Studio versions. So in your case, 2.2.203 is too old and "a recent update of Visual Studio 2019" won't support it. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Comment: @ESG - This is the output.  Note that I just installed 2.2.402 today while trying to solve this issue.  

**2.1.202** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  
**2.1.505** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  
**2.1.509** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  
**2.1.602** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  
**2.2.203** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  
**2.2.402** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]  
**3.0.100** [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: @LexLi - This may be what I need.  I'm testing it out.  A table on that same page indicates that 2.1 is the only LTS release in the 2.x range.  It doesn't have any indication of whether or not 3.0 or 3.1 are going to be supported long-term.  So I suppose I need to be creating 2.1 projects and downgrading my others to that.

Comment: Please take a look at this table https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core and its Status column instead. You also have the typical misunderstanding of LTS/Current lifecycle, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core. Unless you work on a commercial project with quite restricted requirements on product lifecycle, Current releases (like 2.2/3.0) are still feasible versions to use.

Comment: @LexLi - That first link is the one I was referring to when I said 2.2 is near EOL, and no 3.x releases had been marked LTS.  The second link does indicate, however, that 3.1 is an LTS release.  Those links, however, have not fixed my misunderstanding.  Does that table not indicate that one should not have applications in production on 2.2 after 12/23/2019 (less than 2 months from now)?  If you can explain that better, and combine it with the SDKs/VS information into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @LexLi - As it turns out, adding SDKs did not help.  I've updated the question, but it seems that no matter what I do, there is not option, before project creation, to select a version of .NET Core to use for a project.

Comment: 3.1 is LTS but will not differ much from 3.0. The expectation is that if you need LTS, you develop in 3.0 now and switch to 3.1 painlessly when it is released. [I also don't appear to have any option to choose the version of Core before project creation. I suspect that is because MS want you to use v3.x!]